# Игнорировать первых 3 пробела

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Есть скрипт поиска, когда начинаешь вводить символы он тут же выдает совпадения но когда , перед символами вводишь пробелы то совпадения не работают . Подскажите как сделать так , чтоб 3 первых пробела игнорилось в инпуте ?

Вот разметка инпута :

```
     <input id="myinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите слово для поиска" name="phone" required/>
```

вот скрипт поиска :

```
 $("#myinput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#myinput-id").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#myinput-description").html(ui.item.desc);
        $("#myinput-icon").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon).fadeIn('slow');
        });

        return false;
    }
})
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Вот полная версия : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/70/

Comment: Почему именно 3 пробела нужно игнорировать? Почему не 4 или 5, например?

Comment: @Regent, это перестраховка. Думаю  пользователь случайно не введет больше 3 пробелов .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JavaScript у строк есть метод `trim()` - он обрезает все пробелы и символы переноса строк с обоих концов строки.

**UPD**

Для jQuery Autocomplete надо добавить:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var term = $.trim(request.term);
    var reg = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    if (term !== "") {
        response($.grep(projects, function(tag) {
            return tag.label.match(reg);
        }));
    }
},
```

Comment: Добавил UPD в ответ с функцией для autocomplete

Comment: Походу, [теперь работает](http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/71/).

Comment: Работает , спасибо всем )

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - прогоняете введенный текст через `$.trim`. Затем смотрите `length`. Если он больше 0, то, следовательно, есть какой-то текст, кроме пробелов.

Comment: В каком месте исходного кода вы хотите прогнать введённый текст?

Comment: @Regent, вот пример:
`$('#myinput').keyup(function(){

                //если одни пробелы
         $(this).autocomplete("disable");

       });`

Comment: Во-первых, даже если абстрактное "если одни пробелы" перевести в JS-код, то это будет не совсем верно: обрезать пробелы нужно и для _"   шрек"_. Во-вторых, вы уверены, что событие `keyup` будет всегда вовремя отрабатывать? Не может быть такого, что обработчик, который навешивается в Autocomplete, отработает раньше?